# Web scrape results in None

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm having a difficult time extracting the product price below from the Nordstrom website.

```
<div class="_1vV3F"><section id="product-page-price-lockup" class=""><span><span class="_1k-6h _30Yxg">Price</span><span id="current-price-string" class="_1ds4c">$745.00</span>
```

Here's a portion of my code:

```
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "html.parser")
price = soup2.find(class_ = "_1ds4c")
print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select by `id=`:

```
txt = '''<div class="_1vV3F"><section id="product-page-price-lockup" class=""><span><span class="_1k-6h _30Yxg">Price</span><span id="current-price-string" class="_1ds4c">$745.00</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('#current-price-string').text)
```

Prints:

```
$745.00
```

---

Or:

```
print(soup.find(id='current-price-string').text)
```

Prints:

```
$745.00
```